# Powershell and SQL parameters. If empty string, pass DBNull

Tags: sql, powershell, dbnull

I got this parameter:

```
$objDbCmd.Parameters.Add("@telephone", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::VarChar, 18) | Out-Null;
$objDbCmd.Parameters["@telephone"].Value = $objUser.Telephone;
```

Where the string `$objUser.Telephone` can be empty. If it's empty, how can I convert it to `[DBNull]::Value`?

I tried:

```
if ([string]:IsNullOrEmpty($objUser.Telephone)) { $objUser.Telephone = [DBNull]::Value };
```

But that gives me the error:

> Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Failed to convert parameter value from a ResultPropertyValueCollection to a String."

And if I convert it to a string, it inserts an empty string `""`, and not `DBNull`.

How can this be accomplished?

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In PowerShell, you can treat null/empty strings as a boolean.

```
$x = $null
if ($x) { 'this wont print' }

$x = ""
if ($x) { 'this wont print' }

$x = "blah"
if ($x) { 'this will' }
```

So.... having said that you can do:

```
$Parameter.Value = $(if ($x) { $x } else { [DBNull]::Value })
```

But I'd much rather wrap this up in a function like:

```
function CatchNull([String]$x) {
   if ($x) { $x } else { [DBNull]::Value }
}
```

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks Josh. I'll test this later today and then I'll let you know if it solved my problem.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know about powershell, but in C# I would do something like this:

```
if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($objUser.Telephone))
{
 $objDbCmd.Parameters["@telephone"].Value = [DBNull]::Value;
}
else
{
 $objDbCmd.Parameters["@telephone"].Value = $objUser.Telephone;
}
```

Comment: That does work in PowerShell (with one minor tweak - edited to call a static member using PowerShell syntax).  That is what I've done in several scripts and it works properly.

Comment: That would be a solution yes. But I was hoping for a "simpler" solution that doesn't require that much code. Like a function that converts an empty string to DBNull. I got like 60 parameters...

Answer (score 1):

Always append +"" at the end of db values...

$command.Parameters["@EmployeeType"].Value= $ADResult.EmployeeType **+ ""**

Answer (score 1):

Many years later, let me clarify:

[Josh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/81769/josh) shows a helpful simplification for testing strings for emptiness (relying on PowerShell's *implicit* to-Boolean conversion<sup>[1]</sup>), but it is unrelated to Tommy's (the OP's) problem.

Instead, the error message

> "Failed to convert parameter value from a ResultPropertyValueCollection to a String."

implies that **it is the *non*-null case that caused the problem,** because `$objDbCmd.Parameters["@telephone"].Value` expects either a *string* value or `[DBNull]::Value`, whereas `$objUser.Telephone` is of type `[ResultPropertyValueCollection]`, i.e. a *collection* of values.

Thus, in the non-null case, a *string* value must be assigned, which must be derived from the collection; one option is to take the *first* collection element's value, another would be to join all values with a separator to form a single string, using, e.g., `[string]::Join(';', $objUser.Telephone)` or, if joining the elements with *spaces* is acceptable (not a good idea with multiple phone numbers), simply with `"$($objUser.Telephone)"`.<sup>[2]</sup>

Detecting an empty collection via `[string]:IsNullOrEmpty()` actually worked, despite the type mismatch, due to how PowerShell implicitly stringifies collections when passing a value to a `[string]` typed method parameter.<sup>[2]</sup>

Similarly, using *implicit* to-Boolean conversion works as expected with collections too: an empty collection evaluates to `$false`, a non-empty one to `$true`  (as long as there are either at least two elements or the only element by itself would be considered `$true`<sup>[1]</sup>)

Therefore, one solution is to use the *first* telephone number entry:

```
$objDbCmd.Parameters["@telephone"].Value = if ($objUser.Telephone) {
    $objUser.Telephone[0].ToString()  # use first entry
  } else {
    [DBNull]::Value
  }
```

<sup>Note: If `$objUser.Telephone[0]` directly returns a `[string]`, you can omit the `.ToString()` call.</sup>

In **PowerShell v7+** you can alternatively shorten the statement via a ternary conditional:

```
$objDbCmd.Parameters["@telephone"].Value =
  $objUser.Telephone ? $objUser.Telephone[0].ToString() : [DBNull]::Value
```

---

<sup>[1] For a comprehensive summary of PowerShell's automatic to-Boolean conversions, see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375).</sup>

<sup>[2] When *implicitly* converting a collection to a string, PowerShell joins the stringified elements of a collection with a single space as the separator by default; you can override the separator with the automatic `$OFS` variable, but that is rarely done in practice; e.g., array `'foo', 'bar'` is converted to `'foo bar'`; note that this conversion does *not* apply when you call the collection's `.ToString()` method *explicitly*, but it does apply inside expandable (interpolating) strings, e.g., `"$array"`.</sup>