# Powershell: Unable to insert into MySQL date, int values with null

Tags: mysql, powershell

I have a MySQL table `table_foo` with columns `col1` of type `DATETIME` ,`col2` of type int, both accepts `NULL` values but when inserted from Powershell throws error.

```
$oMYSQLCommand.CommandText='INSERT into `table_foo` (`col1`,`col2`) VALUES("' + $null + '", "' + $null + '")'
 $iRowsAffected=$oMYSQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

also tried using `[DBNull]::Value` as  [ref in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507669/sql-insert-from-powershell-null-values-inserted-as-blank)

```
$oMYSQLCommand.CommandText='INSERT into `table_foo` (`col1`,`col2`) VALUES("' + [DBNull]::Value + '", "' + $null + '")'
```

Error

```
Error: Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'col1' at row 1"
```

Comment: concaternating this way you add a string that is the word "null". if you want to insert null you must go like this `INSERT into table_foo (col1,col2) VALUES(null, null)`

Comment: @MaxMuster `null` is not a valid token in powershell

Comment: no  `INSERT INTO table_foo (col1,col2) VALUES(null, null)` is valid mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're constructing a *string* into which the null values are to be *embedded*, you must represent the null values using *SQL* syntax, which means: verbatim `NULL` (without surrounding single quotes):

```
$oMYSQLCommand.CommandText =
  'INSERT into `table_foo` (`col1`,`col2`) VALUES (NULL, NULL)'
```

---

If the values come from PowerShell variables that are *situationally* `$null` and must therefore *conditionally* be translated to verbatim `NULL`, the best approach is to use a helper function, as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61914242/45375).

In the simplest case, with all variables containing *strings*, if you want to treat an *empty string* or a `$null` value as a SQL `NULL`,
you could define a function `tf` (short for: *transform*) as follows:

```
function tf ($val) { 
  if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($val)) { 'NULL' } else { "'{0}'" -f $val } 
}
```

You could then use the function as follows, with `$var1` and `$var2` containing the values to embed:

```
$oMYSQLCommand.CommandText =
  'INSERT into `table_foo` (`col1`,`col2`) VALUES ({0}, {1})' -f
     (tf $var1), (tf $var2)
```

Answer (score 0):

One more simple way of @mklement0's answer is. So the issue here is `MySQL` accepts variable values with quotes and `NULL` without quotes. If `NULL` in enclosed in quotes it is treated as `string` value.  So while using variable concatenate quotes `"` if the variable value is not `NULL`

```
 if($var_x -eq ""){$var_x ="NULL"}else{'var_x = '"'+ $var_x +'"'}
 if($var_y -eq ""){$var_y ="NULL"}else{'var_y = '"'+ $var_y +'"'}
$oMYSQLCommand.CommandText='INSERT into `table_foo` (`col1`,`col2`) VALUES(' + $var_x + ',' + $var_y  + ')'
 $iRowsAffected=$oMYSQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Answer (score -1):

try typing NULL, dont use variable:

```
VALUES('NULL','NULL')
```

something like this:

```
$oMYSQLCommand.CommandText="INSERT into `table_foo' (`col1`,`col2`) VALUES('NULL','NULL')"
```

Comment: thanks @LucasBF but it still throws error :  "Incorrect datetime value: 'NULL' for column 'col1' at row 1"

Comment: From SQL's perspective, `'NULL'` is a _string_, not null - remove the surrounding single quotes.